# Unable to monitor Elasticsearch server logs in kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd, rsyslog

Unable to monitor Elasticsearch server logs in Kibana dashboard.
I have 2 RHEL VMs for testing. I'm using this approach since production have different architecture
VM1- Elasticsearch,Kibana,Rsyslog
VM2 - FluentD

I want to push Elasticsearch logs from VM1 pushing it using Rsyslog and then sending it to VM2 where Fluentd is installed and Fluentd should send back to VM1 Elasticsearch. Below are the configuration.
I've tried installing fluentd in elasticsearch VM and was able to see the elastic logs in kibana.
But my requirement is to use rsyslog and send it to FLuentd. Since, fluentD is not installed in ELasticsearch VM's

td-agent.conf

````
  log_level info
  worker 2
</system>

<source>
  @type tcp
  port 5142
  bind 0.0.0.0
  <parse>
  @type multiline
  format_firstline /^(?<date>\[.*?\])/
  format1 /(?<date>\[.*?\])(?<logLevel>\[.*?\])(?<service>\[.*?\]) (?<node_name>\[.*?\]) (?<LogMessage>.*)/
  </parse>
  tag es_logs
</source>

<source>
  @type syslog
  port 5145
<transport tcp>
  </transport>
  bind 0.0.0.0
  tag syslog
</source>

<filter es_logs**>
  @type parser
  format json
  time_key time_msec
  key_name message
  reserve_data true # tells Fluentd to keep the encompasing JSON - off by default
  remove_key_name_field true # removes the key of the parsed JSON: message - off by default
</filter>

<match es**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host vm1ip
  port 9200
  index_name es_logs_write
  include_timestamp true
  type_name fluentd

  # connection configs
  reconnect_on_error true
  reload_on_failure true
  slow_flush_log_threshold 90

  # buffer configs
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /data/opt/fluentd/buffer/elaticsearch_logs
    chunk_limit_size 2MB
    total_limit_size 1GB
    flush_thread_count 8
    flush_mode interval
    retry_type exponential_backoff
    retry_timeout 10s
    retry_max_interval 30
    overflow_action drop_oldest_chunk
    flush_interval 5s
  </buffer>

</match>```
````

---

rsyslog.conf

```
# Sample rsyslog configuration file
#
$ModLoad imfile
$ModLoad immark
$ModLoad imtcp
$ModLoad imudp
#$ModLoad imsolaris
$ModLoad imuxsock


module(load="omelasticsearch")

template(name="es_logs" type="list" option.json="on") {
    constant(value="{")
    constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"")     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")        property(name="hostname")
    constant(value="\",\"severity-num\":")  property(name="syslogseverity")
    constant(value=",\"facility-num\":")    property(name="syslogfacility")
    constant(value=",\"severity\":\"")      property(name="syslogseverity-text")
    constant(value="\",\"facility\":\"")    property(name="syslogfacility-text")
    constant(value="\",\"syslogtag\":\"")   property(name="syslogtag")
    constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")     property(name="msg")
    constant(value="\"}")
}


$UDPServerRun 514

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog
#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.none;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local6.none    /var/log/messages

# Log auth.info separate
auth.info                                               /var/log/authlog

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog

# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

# ### begin forwarding rule ###
# The statement between the begin ... end define a SINGLE forwarding
# rule. They belong together, do NOT split them. If you create multiple
# forwarding rules, duplicate the whole block!
# Remote Logging (we use TCP for reliable delivery)
#
# An on-disk queue is created for this action. If the remote host is
# down, messages are spooled to disk and sent when it is up again.
$ActionQueueFileName fwdRule1 # unique name prefix for spool files
$ActionQueueMaxDiskSpace 1g # 1gb space limit (use as much as possible)
$ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save messages to disk on shutdown
$ActionQueueType LinkedList # run asynchronously
$ActionResumeRetryCount -1 # infinite retries if host is down
$MaxMessageSize 64k

# remote host is: name/ip:port, e.g. 192.168.0.1:514, port optional
# Forward output to Fluentd

#local8.*                                              /data/elastic_logs/elasticdemo.log
*.* @Vm1Ip:5142;es_logs
```

Comment: I would use the IP instead of the machine name e.g. `*.*  @@10.128.150.10:5142;es_logs`.  Also as mentioned in your comments "... we use TCP ...". When using the old rsyslog format, 1 @ stands for UDP and 2 @s for TCP. As a last thing; are you sure you're receiving both `syslogseverity` and `syslogsevery-text` (same for facility)? Usually only one of each is used in templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the below configurations, created a new file /etc/rsyslog.d/11-elastic.conf
For rsys:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 1
$InputFileName /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticdemo.log
$InputFileTag eslogs:
$InputFileStateFile eslogs
$InputFileFacility local0
$InputRunFileMonitor

:syslogtag, isequal, "eslogs:" {
  :msg, contains, "ERROR" {
    local0.* /var/log/eslog_error.log
    local0.* @fluentdVMip:5141
  }
  stop
}
```

---

For FluentD
td-agent.conf

```
    <system>
  worker 2
</system>


<source>
  @type udp
  port 5141
  tag eslogs
  <parse>
  @type multiline
  format_firstline /^\[(?<date>.*?)\]/
  format1 /\[(?<date>.*?)\]\[(?<logLevel>.*?)\]\[(?<service>.*?)\] \[(?<node_name>.*?)\](?<LogMessage>.*)/
  </parse>
</source>

<match system.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

<match eslogs.**>
  @type elasticsearch
  host ipoftheelasticserver or domain name
  port 9200
  index_name es_logs_write
  include_timestamp true
  type_name fluentd

  # connection configs
  reconnect_on_error true
  reload_on_failure true
  slow_flush_log_threshold 90

  # buffer configs
  <buffer>
    @type file
    path /data/opt/fluentd/buffer/elaticsearch_logs
    chunk_limit_size 2MB
    total_limit_size 1GB
    flush_thread_count 8
    flush_mode interval
    retry_type exponential_backoff
    retry_timeout 10s
    retry_max_interval 30
    overflow_action drop_oldest_chunk
    flush_interval 5s
  </buffer>
</match>
```